# About dictionary list

Tags: python, django

I want to fill a dictionary :

```
    recruitment_dict = {}
    for relation in Relation.objects.filter(on_team=Team.objects.get(owner=request.user)):
        if relation.recruitment is True:
            key = relation.on_game.guid
            value = [relation.on_plateform.guid, relation.recruitment]
            recruitment_dict[key] = value
```

`recruitment_dict` returns this dictionary :

```
{'A': ['b', True], 'B': ['b', True], 'C': ['b', True]}
```

But some values are missing. Sometimes, I should have something like this :

```
{'A': ['b', True], 'A': ['c', True], 'B': ['b', True], 'C': ['b', True]}
```

I think the problem is because I use :

```
recruitment_dict[key] = value
```

And so, only the last object at the end of the boucle "for" is saved.

But I don't know the right synthax to adopt.

Comment: Dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. Every time you assign something to key `'A'`, for example, you overwrite whatever existed before.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys, so you are going to have to think about what you want. Anyway, what would you expect `recuritment_dict['A']` to return??

Comment: Ok I understand.

Comment: I tried with a diferent way. Now my dictionary key is unique and it's quite better ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
if key in recruitment_dict.keys(): 
       recruitment_dict[key].append(value)
else:
       recruitment_dict[key] = value
```

The reason has already been explained in the comments of your questions by others.

If you want to your dictionary to look like this:

```
{'A': [['b', True],['c', True]], 'B': ['b', True], 'C': ['b', True]}
```

then you can use the following.

```
if key in recruitment_dict.keys(): 
           recruitment_dict[key] = [recruitment_dict[key], value]
else:
           recruitment_dict[key] = value
```

Comment: My dictionary returns this : {'A': ['b', True,  ['c', True]], 'B': ['b', True], 'C': ['b', True]}. Is it ok for dealing datas ?

Comment: @see my updated answer. You can create a list of lists in the values if a key exist. For example it will look like this:  {'A': [['b', True], ['c', True]], 'B': ['b', True], 'C': ['b', True]}.  if you want to access each elemenet of that key, you can do recruitment_dict[key][0] or  recruitment_dict[key][1]. It really depends on how you want your dictionary to look like.